# How to disable browser features and shortcut keys to conduct fullscreen online Exam?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am new to OES (Online Exam System). I want to conduct an Online Examination with Secure environment that user will not be able to cheat
please help do this.

I am using `PHP` with `Codeigniter` framework for back end and bootstrap, JS and JQuery for user side or front end.

I have already created a the exam module which is working fine with straight way. but I want to restrict users doing wrong ways tell me the best way to do this or suggest any link where I can get the details about.

Here is My `assessment.php` view file

```
    <?php
    $temp = "";
    $sr_no = 0;
    $assessment = $response['assessment'];
    $test_time = $this->session->userdata('test_time') * 60;
    $questions = $response['questions'];
    $total_que = count($questions);
    $i = $que_no - 1;
    $question = $questions[$i];
    $sr_no++;
    $temp.="<div class='form-group'><input  type='hidden' name='que_id' value='" . $question['que_id'] . "'>";
    if ($total_que == $que_no) {
        $i = $que_no - 1;
        $temp.="<input  type='hidden' name='que_no' value='$i'>";
    } else {
        $temp.="<input  type='hidden' name='que_no' value='$que_no'>";
    }
    $temp.="<label class='col-md-2'>Que. $que_no)</label>
                        <label class='col-md-10'>" . $question['que_dscp'] . "</label>";
    if ($question['que_type'] == "d") {
        $temp.="<div class='col-lg-9 bottom'>";
        if (isset($question['selected_options'])) {
            $temp.="<textarea style='height: 100px;' disabled name='ans_" . $question['que_id'] . "[]'  class='form-control'>" . $question['selected_options'][0] . "</textarea>";
        } else {
            $temp.="<textarea style='height: 100px;' name='ans_" . $question['que_id'] . "[]'  class='form-control'></textarea>";
        }
        $temp.="</div>";
    } else {
        foreach ($question['options'] as $option) {
            $temp.="<div class='col-lg-9 bottom'>
                        <div class='input-group'>
                            <div class='input-group-addon'>";
            if ($question['que_type'] == "ma") {
                if (isset($question['selected_options'])) {
                    if (in_array($option['option_id'], $question['selected_options'])) {
                        $temp.="<input type='checkbox' checked disabled >";
                    } else {
                        $temp.="<input type='checkbox' disabled >";
                    }
                } else {
                    $temp.="<input type='checkbox' name='ans_" . $question['que_id'] . "[]' value='" . $option['option_id'] . "'>";
                }
            } else if ($question['que_type'] == "sa") {
                if (isset($question['selected_options'])) {
                    if (in_array($option['option_id'], $question['selected_options'])) {
                        $temp.="<input type='radio' checked disabled >";
                    } else {
                        $temp.="<input type='radio' disabled >";
                    }
                } else {
                    $temp.="<input type='radio' name='ans_" . $question['que_id'] . "[]' value='" . $option['option_id'] . "'>";
                }
            }
            $temp.="</div>
                            <input type='text' readonly value='" . $option['option_dscp'] . "' class='form-control'>
                        </div>
                    </div>";
        }
    }
    $temp.="</div>";
    $temp1 = "";
    $sr_no = 0;
    foreach ($questions as $question1) {
        $sr_no++;
        $temp1.="<a href='" . base_url() . "user/assessment/index/" . $assessment['test_id'] . "/$sr_no' class='btn btn-info'>$sr_no</a> ";
    }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resource/js/TimeCircles.js"></script>
    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resource/css/TimeCircles.css" rel="stylesheet">     
    <div class="container">    
        <div class="page-header center">
            <h1><?php echo $assessment['test_name']; ?> <small><?php echo $title; ?> </small></h1>
        </div>
        <?php $this->load->view('alert'); ?>
        <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4" style="padding: 0;">
            <!-- Default panel contents -->
            <div class="panel-heading">Questions Navigation</div>
            <div class="panel-body" >
                <?php echo "$temp1"; ?>
            </div>
            <div id="test_time" data-timer="<?php echo "$test_time"; ?>"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default col-md-8" style="padding: 0;">
            <!-- Default panel contents -->
            <div class="panel-heading">Assessment Questions</div>
            <div class="panel-body" >
                <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
                <form id="signupform" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/assessment/submit" class="form-horizontal" method="POST"> 
                    <input type="hidden" name='test_id' value='<?php echo $assessment['test_id']; ?>'>
                    <input type="hidden" name='user_id' value='<?php echo $this->session->userdata('user_id'); ?>'>
                    <?php echo "$temp"; ?>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <!-- Button --> 
                        <div class="col-md-offset-6 col-md-6">
                            <?php
                            if ($que_no == 1) {
                                ?>
                                <a href="#" disabled class='btn btn-danger'>Previous</a>
                                <?php
                            } else {
                                ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/assessment/index/<?php echo $assessment['test_id']; ?>/<?php echo ($que_no - 1); ?>" class='btn btn-info'>Previous</a>
                                <?php
                            }
                            if (isset($question['selected_options'])) {
                                ?>
                                <button id="btn-signup" disabled type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-hand-right"></i> &nbsp Save</button>
                                <?php
                            } else {
                                ?>
                                <button id="btn-signup" type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-hand-right"></i> &nbsp Save</button>
                                <?php
                            }
                            if ($total_que == $que_no) {
                                ?>
                                <a href="#" disabled class='btn btn-danger'>Next</a>
                                <?php
                            } else {
                                ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/assessment/index/<?php echo $assessment['test_id']; ?>/<?php echo ($que_no + 1); ?>" class='btn btn-info'>Next</a>
                                <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" id="time_taken" name="time_taken" >
                    <div id="Countdown" style="width: 50%;"></div>
                </form>
                <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/assessment/solved/<?php echo $assessment['test_id']; ?>/<?php echo $this->session->userdata('user_id'); ?>" class='btn btn-info'>Finish Test</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $("#test_time").TimeCircles();
        $("#Countdown").TimeCircles({
            "animation": "smooth",
            "bg_width": 0.8,
            "fg_width": 0.1,
            "circle_bg_color": "#60686F",
            "time": {
                "Days": {
                    "text": "Days",
                    "color": "#FFCC66",
                    "show": false
                },
                "Hours": {
                    "text": "Hours",
                    "color": "#99CCFF",
                    "show": false
                },
                "Minutes": {
                    "text": "Minutes",
                    "color": "#BBFFBB",
                    "show": true
                },
                "Seconds": {
                    "text": "Seconds",
                    "color": "#FF9999",
                    "show": true
                }
            }
        });

        $("#btn-signup").click(function() {
            $("#time_taken").val($("#Countdown").TimeCircles().getTime());
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        setInterval(ajaxCall, 1000); //300000 MS == 5 minutes
        function ajaxCall() {
            var test_time=$("#test_time").TimeCircles().getTime();
            if(test_time >= 0){
                $.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/assessment/set_test_time", { test_time : test_time }, function(data, status) {
                    });
            }else{
                 $.get("<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/assessment/solved/<?php echo $assessment['test_id']; ?>/<?php echo $this->session->userdata('user_id'); ?>",function(data, status) {
                       location.reload();
                    });
            }

        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
          $(document).bind('contextmenu', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
          });
        });
        function disableF5(e) { if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 116 ||(e.which || e.keyCode)==8) e.preventDefault(); };
        $(document).on("keydown", disableF5);

    </script>
```

Here is My `home.php` view file from where I redirect user to `assessment.php`

```
<?php
$temp = "";
$sr_no = 0;
foreach ($assessments as $assessment) {
    $solved = $assessment['solved'];
    $test_id = $assessment['test_id'];
    $test_name = $assessment['test_name'];
    $status = $assessment['status'];
    if ($status == "1") {
        $status = "Active";
    } else {
        $status = "InActive";
    }
    $sr_no++;
    $temp.="<tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>$sr_no</td>
                <td>$test_name</td>
                <td>$status</td>";
                 if($solved=="0"){
                    $temp.="<td><a target='_blank' class='btn btn-info' onClick='return confirm(\"Are you sure want to Start Assessment...!\");' href='javascript:window.open(\"".base_url()."user/assessment/index/$test_id\",\"User Assessment\", \"titlebar=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,width=screen.width,height=screen.height,fullscreen=yes\");' title='Take Test'>Take Test</a></td>";     
                 }else if($solved=="1"){
                    $temp.="<td><a class='ml10' href='".base_url()."user/assessment/view/$test_id' title='View'>
                    <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></i></a></td>";
                 }   
        $temp.="</tr>";
}
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resource/css/bootstrap-table.css">
<div class="container">    
    <div class="page-header center">
        <h1>User Assessment System! User Dashboard <small><?php echo $title; ?> </small></h1>
    </div>
    <?php $this->load->view('alert'); ?>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <!-- Default panel contents -->
        <div class="panel-heading">Manage Assessment</div>
        <div class="panel-body" >
            <!-- Table -->
            <table class="table" id="userstable" data-toggle="table" data-pagination="true"  data-show-refresh="true" data-export-types="{'pdf','xml','joson','png','excel'}" data-show-export="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th data-field="que_dscp" data-sortable="true">Assessment Name</th>
                        <th data-field="status" class="text-center">Status</th>
                        <th data-field="ques" class="text-center">Start/View Test</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php echo "$temp"; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table><br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resource/js/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
<!-- put your locale files after bootstrap-table.js -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resource/js/bootstrap-table-en-US.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can't _reliably_ disable those keys.

Comment: Is there any other option / approach I can use for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no way for you to *restrict* someone in a location not controlled by you.
No matter what you do to my browser or even my operating system, I can always just use a second computer, or my phone, or have a book lying around, or a sheet of paper, or a friend who knows stuff.

The only way to detect such a thing would be a camera filming the user the entire time.
In addition to that, you'd have to film the screen - with a camera too, not via a screen recorder, because otherwise I might just use a virtual machine for the exam, in which the browser is in full screen all the time, but I can just alt-Tab out of the VM and do whatever I want, while a screen recorder will just see the inside of the VM.

So you cannot actually *restrict* the user - the only thing you can try is to *surveil* them.
That would require at the very least one microphone and two cameras, probably more - one to film the screen (so that you can actually recognise something afterwards) and the rest to film the user and his entire possible field of view (don't forget the ceiling, there could be writing or something). The microphone, of course, is to make sure the user has no audible input during the exam - this also implies that they must not wear headphones, otherwise they might make use of some sound-based interface.
For example, I imagine a service which, upon activation by hotkey, opens an invisible browser window, captures your keyboard input, conducts a Google search upon hitting <kbd>Return</kbd>, lets you navigate via the arrow keys/<kbd>Return</kbd>/<kbd>Tab</kbd>/<kbd>Backspace</kbd>/<kbd>Esc</kbd> and reads to you any text that you "select".
I believe on OS X, one would only need to find a way to make windows invisible - then they could activate Voice over, set their start page to Google and create a service with Automator that opens a new browser window (invisibly), to which they can then assign a hotkey.
Also, all recordings should be transmitted in real time, otherwise the user has a chance to tamper with them.

Now that I wrote this I realise that this is probably more of a question for [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This might help you partially,
You can suppress few keydown events which might help you partially, You won't be able to disable all the events though,

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    // if the keyCode is 16 ( shift key was pressed )
    // Here you can specify which key events you want to disable
    if ((event.which || event.keyCode) === 16) {
        // prevent default behaviour
        event.preventDefault();
        // Few Browser also need return false, to disable keydown events
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For limited browser capabilities,
You can use Javascript's `window.open` function, it takes certain parameters. For example look below

If you look at the `third parameters`, it does the tricks that you are looking for, it disables the `toolbar` and all those stuffs.

```
window.open('exampage.html','some_name_for_this_window','titlebar=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,width=400,height=350');
```

Take a look at the Mozilla [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) for what other features you can disable or enable. It might help you out

And on the backend for what the user is clicking and interacting, you have codeigniter's `SESSION` library to take care of that

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31019397/need-secure-web-browser-to-use-for-quiz-application) which was closed. After some online search, found out this amazing software called [safeexambrowser](http://www.safeexambrowser.org/news_en.html) which currently works for windows and mac os.  Built on Firefox/ gecko engine, it will help you to disable keyboard shortcuts and refrains user from using any other application.

This is suitable for standallone web applications. Please check if this suits your requirement.